# Mvc3: working with the page layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Layout page that has a fixed header with few hyperlinks

When you click on a link I want to display  a two column page
which will have a left navigation and content will be to the right

The left navigation will have hyperlinks as well which can be clicked
and content should always display on the right. Every link on top will have
different left navigation content when displayed

..Right now what I have is that when I click on the left navigation,
content is displayed but the left navigation column disappears.

How can I fix this?

Main layout

---

```
        <body>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="Test-logo"></div>
                    <div class="menucontrol-x"></div>
                </div>  <!-- end "header" -->
                <div class="mainNav">
                    <ul class="menuMain1">
                        <li><a alt="" href="">My Info</a></li>
                        <li><a alt="" href="">My Result</a></li> 
                        <li><a alt="" href="">My Deliveries</a></li> 
                        <li><a alt="" href="">Messages</a></li> 
                        <li><a alt="" href="">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a alt="" href="">Settings</a></li> 
                        <li><a alt="Frequently Asked Questions" href="">FAQ</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="menuMain2">
                        <li><a alt="Sign out" href="">Sign Out</a></li>
                        <li><a alt="Shop at our online store" href="">My Store</a></li> 
                    </ul>   
                </div><!-- end "mainNav" -->

                <div id="sidebar">
                    @RenderSection("SideBar",required:false)
                </div>

                <div id="content">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>

            <div class="footer">
                    <ul class="menuFooter1">
                        <li><a alt="Contact Us" href="">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a alt="Shop at our online store" href="">Online Store</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- end "footer" -->
            </div>
        </body>
```

Child view

---

```
        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";
            Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSecondMaster.cshtml";


        }


        @section SideBar
        {

        <div class="subMenu">
                    <ul class="services">
                        <li><a alt="" href="@Url.Action("Garments","Dots")">Garments</a></li>
                        <li>Products</li> 
                        <li>Special Order History</li> 
                        <li>My Service Team</li> 
                    </ul>

                </div><!-- end "subMenu" -->
                <div class="miscNav">
                    <p>View our <a alt="Terms &amp; Conditions" href="">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>.</p>
                    <p>Visit our other Cool sites:</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a alt="testing1.com" href="">Stuff.com</a></li>
                        <li><a alt="Store.Testing.com" href="//store.testing.com">Store.testing.com</a></li>            
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- end "miscNav" -->
                    <div class="smProduct1">
                        <h3>Product Representation<br /> (smProduct1)</h3>
                    </div> <!-- end "smProduct1" --> 

        }

        <div class="whatever">    
            <h2>Product</h2>
            Here you go buddy!Here you go buddy!Here you go buddy!Here you go buddy!Here you go buddy!
            Here you go buddy!Here you go buddy!Here you go buddy!Here you go buddy!Here you go buddy!    
        </div>
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. Are you sure the SideBar is defined on the page you are navigating to? And you didn't make a typo?

Comment: Yes it is defined. Maybe I need to make this an Ajax call so that the left column will not disappear again. What do you think?

Comment: An Ajax call is nice, but your approach should work as well. To make sure, the Main layout in your post is the `_LayoutSecondMaster.cshtml`?

Comment: Yes it is. I wonder why the left column is disappearing.

Comment: Pretty strange indeed, you can set the `required:false` to true, then it will throw an exception if no SideBar is defined.

Comment: I just did and it didn't throw an exception

Comment: I have tried your code in an empty MVC project and the view is displayed correctly. I'm affraid I have no idea why your sidebar isnt showing.